# numpy - Comparing two elements of a matrix and filling in the relative value in a different position

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have an 12 x 12 matrix with only the first row and column filled. The matrix below,

```
[['-' 'T' 'S' 'V' 'K' 'Y' 'A' 'F' 'H' 'L' 'P' 'Q']
['T' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '']
['S' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '']
['V' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '']
['K' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '']
['Y' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '']
['A' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '']
['F' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '']
['H' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '']
['L' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '']
['P' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '']
['Q' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '']]
```

What I have to do now is compare each element of the first row with each of the first column to see if they are the same or different (For eg., TT, SS or SV,KS), ignoring the order of the letters (i.e. SV is to be considered the same as VS). I'm trying to use the following for loop,

```
for x in np.nditer(matrix,op_flags=['readwrite'],op_dtypes=['str']):
```

However, I'm not sure how to access each element using a for loop and compare them with a different element in a different position. Also, I'm not sure how to write the result of this comparison to a different position in the matrix. I'm not very familiar with numpy but I've looked at the questions that already exist and none of them seem to help me. Is this possible to do in numpy?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I figured that doing this within the matrix is a little more complicated and time consuming. So I basically just created a matrix filled with zeros, declared a list with the unique letters I want to compare. I did two nested for loop to compare the index of each element with every other element and performed operations on it depending on whether the index is same or not!

Comment: So I followed something similar to what G M suggested. The code as follows,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use simply python without using numpy for this work you can access and write array simply using the notation a[subarray][index] as shown in the solution:

```
a=[['-','T','S','V','K','Y','A','F','H','L','P','Q'],
['T','','','','','','','','','','',''],
['S','','','','','','','','','','',''],
['V','','','','','','','','','','',''],
['K','','','','','','','','','','',''],
['Y','','','','','','','','','','',''],
['A','','','','','','','','','','',''],
['F','','','','','','','','','','',''],
['H','','','','','','','','','','',''],
['L','','','','','','','','','','',''],
['P','','','','','','','','','','',''],
['Q','','','','','','','','','','',''],]

def comparematrix(a):
    for i in a[0][1:]:#loop over the first row (note skip first element!)
        for j in range(1,len(a)):#loop over number of rows
            print a[j][0],i
            if a[j][0]==i:#find if they are equal
                    a[j][a[0].index(i)]='couple!'
            else:
                 a[j][a[0].index(i)]='%s,%s'%(a[j][0],i)
    return a
```

Eventually you can make a numpy array if you want, but I think this is not a conventional example of using numpy array because is not strictly a real computation.

```
[['-', 'T', 'S', 'V', 'K', 'Y', 'A', 'F', 'H', 'L', 'P', 'Q'],

['T', 'couple!', 'T,S', 'T,V', 'T,K', 'T,Y', 'T,A', 'T,F', 'T,H', 'T,L', 'T,P', 'T,Q'], 

['S', 'S,T', 'couple!', 'S,V', 'S,K', 'S,Y', 'S,A', 'S,F', 'S,H', 'S,L', 'S,P', 'S,Q'], 

['V', 'V,T', 'V,S', 'couple!', 'V,K', 'V,Y', 'V,A', 'V,F', 'V,H', 'V,L', 'V,P', 'V,Q'], 

['K', 'K,T', 'K,S', 'K,V', 'couple!', 'K,Y', 'K,A', 'K,F', 'K,H', 'K,L', 'K,P', 'K,Q'], 

['Y', 'Y,T', 'Y,S', 'Y,V', 'Y,K', 'couple!', 'Y,A', 'Y,F', 'Y,H', 'Y,L', 'Y,P', 'Y,Q'], 

['A', 'A,T', 'A,S', 'A,V', 'A,K', 'A,Y', 'couple!', 'A,F', 'A,H', 'A,L', 'A,P', 'A,Q'], 

['F', 'F,T', 'F,S', 'F,V', 'F,K', 'F,Y', 'F,A', 'couple!', 'F,H', 'F,L', 'F,P', 'F,Q'], 

['H', 'H,T', 'H,S', 'H,V', 'H,K', 'H,Y', 'H,A', 'H,F', 'couple!', 'H,L', 'H,P', 'H,Q'], 

['L', 'L,T', 'L,S', 'L,V', 'L,K', 'L,Y', 'L,A', 'L,F', 'L,H', 'couple!', 'L,P', 'L,Q'], 

['P', 'P,T', 'P,S', 'P,V', 'P,K', 'P,Y', 'P,A', 'P,F', 'P,H', 'P,L', 'couple!', 'P,Q'], 

['Q', 'Q,T', 'Q,S', 'Q,V', 'Q,K', 'Q,Y', 'Q,A', 'Q,F', 'Q,H', 'Q,L', 'Q,P', 'couple!']]
```

Comment: Thanks! I took a similar approach and was able to get what I want without numpy :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. If I understand you correctly:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[4,6,7,8],[3,10,11,12],[1,13,14,15]])
>>> a
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 4,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 3, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 1, 13, 14, 15]])
>>> b = a[0]
>>> b
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a.transpose()[0]
array([1, 4, 3, 1])
>>> c = a.transpose()[0]
>>> c
array([1, 4, 3, 1])
>>> for x in b:
...     for y in c:
...             if x == y:
...                     print "Do this if y=%d is equal to x=%d"%(y,x)
...             else:
...                     print "Do that if y=%d is not equal to x=%d"%(y,x)
...
Do this if y=1 is equal to x=1
Do that if y=4 is not equal to x=1
Do that if y=3 is not equal to x=1
Do this if y=1 is equal to x=1
Do that if y=1 is not equal to x=2
Do that if y=4 is not equal to x=2
Do that if y=3 is not equal to x=2
Do that if y=1 is not equal to x=2
Do that if y=1 is not equal to x=3
Do that if y=4 is not equal to x=3
Do this if y=3 is equal to x=3
Do that if y=1 is not equal to x=3
Do that if y=1 is not equal to x=4
Do this if y=4 is equal to x=4
Do that if y=3 is not equal to x=4
Do that if y=1 is not equal to x=4
```

What I do is taking first row from given matrix by `b = a[0]` then [transposing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) the original matrix and taking first row from result `c = a.transpose()[0]` which basically means I just took a first column of original one. That way you have array `b` - first row elements, and `c` - first column elements. You can do with them now whatever you want. What I did is: *for each element in `b` look for it in `c` and print it out if found one*

Comment: Hello, 
This code would be perfect if what I wanted to do was to check if a particular element is there in a column or not. However, what I wanted to do was to compare each element of the first row with every other element of the first column and perform operations on them depending on whether they are same or not. I really appreciate the reply though and I also learnt the transpose function from your reply. Thank you for taking the time :)

Comment: Hi. I updated my answer to meet your requirements as I understand them. Please provide your solution with a code (I saw your comment to the original question) using `Answer Your Question` button, I am not sure but it seems like code you described could be wrong for the most cases.

Answer (score 0):

So I followed something similar to what G M suggested. The code as follows,

```
def freq_pair(output_pa):
# Creating matrix using the list with 12 rows and 12 columns
aa = ['T','S','V','K','Y','A','F','H','L','P','Q']

nrows = len(aa)
ncols = len(aa)
#print nrows,ncols

matrix = np.zeros((nrows,ncols))      
print(matrix)

#Looping through the matrix to change the value to frequency of occurence
for item in aa:
    for itemB in aa:
        if aa.index(item) != aa.index(itemB):
            eab = float((output_pa[item][1])) * float((output_pa[itemB][1]))*2
        else:
            eab = float((output_pa[item][1])) * float((output_pa[itemB][1]))

            #print(eab)
        matrix[aa.index(item), aa.index(itemB)] = eab
return matrix
```

output_pa is a dictionary with the letters as key and their frequency and frequency / total frequency as values. This essentially gave me the desired output in much less time than anything else!